# Execute loop only if text field is NOT empty

Tags: javascript, is-empty

As per the below, I have a form with a list of questions and text boxes to capture the answers from the users.

```
<form name="myform">
<ul id="Jtest">
<li>Your favourite music?   <textarea rows="2" cols="50" ></textarea></li>
<li>The best holiday you had?   <textarea rows="2" cols="50" ></textarea></li>
<li>Your ideal job? <textarea rows="2" cols="50"></textarea></li>
</ul>
</form> 

<input type="text" /><button onclick="FormSave()">Save</button>
```

Once the user completes the form I want to save all the questions along with the answers - except when the user has not answered a question. So if the user didn't answer a question then I don't want to save the question either.
I have the below code, which works except for the argument for checking if the text field is empty (x.elements[i].value !== ""). I've tried a few operators and combinations for empty field, but no luck.

```
function FormSave() {

var output2 = document.getElementById("Jtest").getElementsByTagName("li");
var output = [];
var x = document.forms[0];
var content = "";
var i;

  for (i = 0; ((i < x.length) && (x.elements[i].value !== "")); i++) {
  content = content + output2[i].textContent + x.elements[i].value + "\r\n"; 
  }

}
```

Comment: You could change it to trim and check the length ex: x.elements[i].value.trim().length

Comment: @osekmedia. Still no luck. I tried writing on screen a specific element value (`..innerHTML=x.elements[5].value;`) and it works, but for some reason when I want to check if the value is not empty it doesn't work.